# How can I change the color of the bottom border of my ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin.android

I'm trying to achieve a bottom border effect for my ActionBar, similar to this image:

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">#088A29</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#088A29</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">#0B3B0B</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
```

I've added a margin at the bottom, but the margin appears white. How can I change the color of this bottom margin to match the ActionBar background color?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me the following solution worked perfectly and smooth.

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background_bar</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
```

And of course I built the custom_background_bar that I saved into drawable forlder.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:top="-3dp" android:right="-3dp" android:left="-3dp">
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      <stroke
          android:width="2dp"
          android:color="#ff00ff00" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

You are free to change #ffff0000 (the background bar color) and #ff00ff00 (the bottom border color) with the values you prefer.
You can change also then thickness and style of the border or add other shape and elements inside the layer-list.
You can also set again another drawable as background and give shade or transparency as you prefer.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Using the above technique I am also getting a border under the title as well. How to avoid ?

Comment: For me and 7 other people it works fine. On which devices/emulators you are getting the border? Did you put padding negative and/or check if the border you are seeing is due to other code?

Comment: The border beneath title is caused by the drawable i am using as a background for the action bar. No emulator on device.

Comment: Great answer.  But the android:layout_marginBottom is not necessary

Answer (score 3):

Play Newsstand uses a custom 9-patch with a small drop shadow for its `ActionBar` background.

But generally the shadow below the `ActionBar` can be altered by applying `Drawable` to your theme using the [`windowContentOverlay` attribute](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout.java).

Here's an example:

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Here are the 9-patches Play Newsstand uses:

- [MDPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruCu3.png) - [image: MDPI]
- [HDPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P5UB.png)- [image: HDPI]
- [XHDPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5X7o.png)- [image: XHDPI]

Alternatively, you could use the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), which will automagically add it for you to your `ActionBar` background `Drawable`.